# asp.net: convert URL to plain text

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my model I have an imageURL:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
```

and in my view I have the following:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ImageURL)
```

Now this will produce the following HTML markup:

```
<a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Full_suspension_mountain_bike.jpg">http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Full_suspension_mountain_bike.jpg</a>
```

Now what I want is to simply get the URL as a plain text.. so something like this (without "a href" and brackets):

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Full_suspension_mountain_bike.jpg
```

How can I do this? The reason why I want this is because after this  I actually want to convert it into an image, as follows:

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Full_suspension_mountain_bike.jpg"/>
```

Comment: <img src="@Model.ImageURL"/> ?

Comment: thanks, this is what I was looking for :) sorry for the noob question.